# Null Pointer Exception JavaFX

Tags: java

o que há de errado com o seguinte trecho do meu código ?

```
public static void retorna(BufferedImage bufImage) throws IOException {
    // String file = new String("test.png");
    // setTfFoto(bufImage);


    Image image = null;
    SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufImage, (WritableImage) image);

    //SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufImage, image);

    tfFoto.setImage(image);
    System.out.println("imprimiu a foto na tela");

}
```

tfFoto é um ImageView criado usando FXML porém não consigo de forma alguma receber esse BufferedImage de outro metodo e faze-lo aparecer em minha interface.

Alguem poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Qual é a linha que dá o erro?

Comment: Consegui remover os erros de compilação. porém o ImageView Chamado tfFoto eu nao consigo faze-lo exibir a imagem que é passado por parametro por um outro metodo que se encontra em outra classe.

Comment: Se preferir posso postar todo o projeto no github para voce poder ve-lo melhor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Image image = null;
SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufImage, (WritableImage) image);
```

Você está tentando fazer cast de null para WritableImage.
Pra isso funcionar você precisa instanciar/injetar Image de alguma forma.